# How to disable layer(not hide) in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

In my map, I have  multiple layers. 
For certain operations I want to only work on one layer. The other layers should be visible, but disabled, so that they can not be selected or interacted with in any way.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling a layer?

Comment: in my project i have 4 layers, when am working on layer 1. layer 2,3,4 should be disabled(means user should only be able to see the layer 2,3,4 but not able to select any feature from that layer) 

does anybody know, how that can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass in the layers option for ol.control.Select and only pass in the layer you want to edit.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html?unstable=true

layers  Array. | function   experimental
A list of layers from which features should be selected. Alternatively, a filter function can be provided. The function will be called for each layer in the map and should return true for layers that you want to be selectable. If the option is absent, all visible layers will be considered selectable.